# Get the generic type of a generic type

Tags: java

I apologize in advance, I'm sure this has been asked before, but I'm a self-learned programmer so I can't for the life of me figure out the terms I need to search for.

I have a generic class:

```
public abstract class Directory<T extends Key>
```

It is a generic parameter of another class:

```
public class TagDescriptor<T extends Directory, U extends Key>
```

The `U` of `TagDescriptor` will always be the generic parameter of the `Directory` passed as the first parameter.  It's fine to pass the `T`, but is there no way to infer the `U`?  I've tried things like:

```
public class TagDescriptor<T extends Directory<U>>
```

But that's incorrect.  At compile time it should know that `Directory` has a generic; can I leverage that?

Comment: `public class TagDescriptor<T extends Directory<U>, U extends Key>`. [Works here](http://ideone.com/8r4pHJ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare multiple **types parameters** bounded with self-reference:

```
public class TagDescriptor<K extends Key, T extends Directory<K>>
```

NB: `K` is commonly [used, as a name, for key types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html).

As for, why is it necessary to *declare* the type parameter K? Well it's quite simple : because otherwise the compiler has no way to tell what K is : a concrete class, an interface named K ? Or a type parameter named K ?

For instance, this would be perfectly legal:

```
public interface K {}

public class TagDescriptor<T extends Directory<K>>
```

Comment: Yes, but that's redundant, my question if it wasn't clear is "Why isn't `Directory<K>` sufficient by itself", `K` is defined in that case in `Directory<K extends Key>`

Comment: Oh, it's just verbosity to ensure there isn't name collision.  I didn't even think about single character classes/interfaces.  Thanks.